# How to reset everything on label in onclick method

Tags: java, gwt, onclick, label

I am printing multiple labels and on click I am changing the clicked label color. I want to reset the clicked label color when I click on another label.

```
final Label functionLabel = new Label(FDTO.getFunctionName());
functionLabel.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        functionLabel.getElement().getStyle().setColor("red");
        // checkChild(FDTO.getFunctionCode(), functions, qaDTO, val);
    }
});

childPanel.add(functionLabel);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike `RadioButton`s which can be grouped together, `Label`s are stand-alone elements, and there's no out-of-the-box way of doing what you want.

The most straightforward way to do so would be to manually change the color of every other label from within this label's `onClick` method, either one by one or iterating through some list/array where you keep them all.
Something along the lines of:

```
List<Label> myLabels = Arrays.asList(functionLabel, errorLabel, someOtherLabel);
//...
functionLabel.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        for (Label l : myLabels) {
            l.getElement().getStyle().setColor("black");
        }
        functionLabel.getElement().getStyle().setColor("red");
        // checkChild(FDTO.getFunctionCode(), functions, qaDTO, val);
    }
});
```

Comment: @niko You said you were printing multiple labels but didn't include their names in your code, so I made up some names for them. Just replace them with the labels whose color you want to be switched back on click.